Are my conceptions about the Lagrangian of the LP formulation of a zero-sum game inaccurate?
Consider the zero-sum game $A = \begin{bmatrix}5 & 3 \\ 4 & -3\end{bmatrix}$.  The interpretation is that Row Player chooses a probability distribution over Top and Bottom $\vec x = \begin{bmatrix}\Pr(Top) \\ 1 - \Pr(Top)\end{bmatrix}$, Column Player chooses a probability distribution over Left and Right $\vec y = \begin{bmatrix}\Pr(Left) \\ 1 - \Pr(Left)\end{bmatrix}$, and then each distribution is realized and Column Player pays Row Player the payoff.
As I understand, $\vec x^T A \vec y$ is the Lagrangian of the game's Linear Programming formulation, which turns out to be $6\Pr(Top) - 5\Pr(Top)\Pr(Left) + 7\Pr(Left) - 3$.  I graphed this surface in Mathematica (from $-1$ to $2$ for context despite the inputs being probabilities).

The Nash Equilibrium (the green point on the graph) occurs at $(1, 0)$ ($\Pr(Top) = 1$ and $\Pr(Left) = 0$).  I expected this to occur at a saddle point.  There is a saddle point (the blue point on the graph) at $(\frac{7}{5}, \frac{6}{5})$, but the two points do not coincide.  In fact, the Nash Equilibrium is not even as close to the saddle point as possible within the valid probability region, which would be the point $(1, 1)$.
I did not know until recently that the term saddle point (also?) refers to the geometry of the discrete surface above/below a zero-sum game matrix obtained by treating the payoffs as heights, and the Nash Equilibrium behaves like a saddle point in that geometry.  Is that the only interpretation, or are Nash Equilibria (given certain conditions?) saddle points in the Lagrangian surface as well (I thought the latter was related to swapping player order in the sequential version of the game and the Minimax Theorem)?  Are the discrete surface and the Lagrangian surface related?  Is there some way to extend/ignore the concept of probability to give meaning to the point $(\frac{7}{5}, \frac{6}{5})$ as the players' optimal mixing weights or some other less standard concept (just as the complex numbers were invented to give meaning to the otherwise unintelligible)?
